# How to handle conditions in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have tried to update option id value in template class based on Boolean flag , Basically I am handling drop down list and drop down list contains id's. Here I am trying to update id value based on boolean flag, but getting some error's like "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:" .

This is my template:

```html
<div class="bx--col-md-1">
     <select id="select-menu" class="bx--text-input" required  name="actionSelection" (change)="onActionChange($event)" (dblclick)="onActionChange($event)">          
       <option  *ngFor="let action of actions"  [value]="action.id" >{{action.name}}</option> 
     </select>
 </div>
```

here 'Changeval' is one of my boolean flag in .ts file and default it would be false. But some moment it will change to true. When this will become true, need to update action.id value need to make 0 in template class. Could any one please help me, how to update. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure to post your questions with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use stackblitz.com for angular projects

Comment: Could you post some of the code of your component? I do not see any "Changeval" in the template and I do not know what you mean.

Comment: @hjbello 'changeval'  will be their in class file with the value false, and some operations it will change to true. While this changed to true, need to update action.id value to be 0(zero).

Answer (score 0):

I find it quite hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Though, you could try this:

```
[value]="changeval == false ? action.id : 0"
```

It's a ternary operator, it tests the `changeval` variable.
If `changeval` is false, will use `action.id`. If it's true, will use `0`.

Comment: Thank you so much  for your answer, yes this is what I am looking. Is this statement need to add in option tag?

Comment: Simply replace your current `<option>` `[value]` binding to this one.

Comment: But I need both functionalities, If  changeval true then only this [value]="changeval == false ? action.id : 0" need to work otherwise my previous one need to be work. Even though that is working fine, but doubt is like how to use both.